# Entity Framework code-first or database-first when there are a lot of stored procedures

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

We have some ASP.NET webforms applications, and we want to migrate to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework.

We have a lot of stored procedures in SQL Server, so we need to call them in from the ASP.NET MVC application.

The question is: which one is more suitable?

- Entity Framework database-first
- Entity Framework code-first

Comment: Suitability is not a question any more. Database-first is deprecated. And for calling stored procedures there are many more options, like Dapper.

Comment: thanks Arnold, seems Dapper is good advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is strongly biassed and opinion based:

I would go for code first: always... (well.. except if the application is on the end of it's lifetime)

As for your stored procedures; you can add them by applying a custom migration.

2 of the main benefits:

- no tooling dependencies (diagrams and such) (in the past these could be slow)
- no manual touching the database and full configuration by code (so the code is always right)

Since it's a migration; you might want to generate your code first code based on an existing db.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server database project to manage your schema, and DB First with EF.

Comment: thanks Erik, what about, If you want to write an Application from scratch and create tables and sp from scratch, I mean completely a new project without existing database?